# Use more than one type package of multiple aws sdk services

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, types, aws-sdk

I am using multiple services in my golang project and want to use the types package from more than one service. ie "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs/types" & "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types".

I cannot import and use both as it only accepts the first package in the import statement and I cannot use the other services types package.

I know I must be doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Import as when two package names conflict.

```
cwtypes "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs/types"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3/types"
```